# Get a hotel registration # in Gewerberegister in Germany for the purpose of Schengen Visa application

Tags: germany, hotels, schengen-visas

This is a spillover question from [How to apply for a German Schengen visa, staying in a small hotel with no registration #](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95210/how-to-apply-for-a-german-schengen-visa-staying-in-a-small-hotel-with-no-regist)

I need to get a Schengen visa to stay in Germany for 6 nights in mid-Rhineland area (Koblenz and vicinity). In Schengen visa application, there is a section for "reference" (german Referenz (Angaben zu einladender Person/Institution)), where you are supposed to put your hotel name, registry name (Name des Registers der Organisation) and number the hotel has in this particular registry (Registernummer). The registries proposed in the VIDEX form are:

1. Gewerberegister
2. Handelsregister
3. Partnerschaftsregister
4. Vereinsregister
   5 Genossenschaftsregister
5. Sonstige deutsche oder ausländische Register (other register)

I contacted 5 hotels in the area that I liked with the question:

> Please provide me your registration number in Gewerberegister

One of them replied:

> as singleowner of a Hotel are we not registered in the Gewerberegister

the others seemed to silently ignore my question.

Questions:

1. My understanding that almost every income producing entity has to be
   registered in Gewerberegister. How do I find this number for a hotel
   that I like?
2. How do I locate a hotel that is willing to share this number? How do I even start to search for that?
3. Is it possible to apply and successfully receive the visa if I do not know the hotel Gewerberegister (or other registers) number?

Comment: I checked my last application for Germany Schengen Tourist Visa, on VIDEX, I only answered 31a, b, c questions, with info from booking.com hotel booking confirmation, just hotel name, address, phone, email. And yes, I got visa, and visited and enjoyed :)

Comment: 1: I don’t think you can other than calling the respective town and asking them, while somehow proving that your request is legitimate. And since we are talking German civil servants do not expect their English to be good at all. 2: I wouldn’t have the slightest of clues. Larger companies are typically requested to publish their *Handelsregisternummer* in a number of areas (e.g. on their company letter paper or a website’s impressum) but I have never seen anybody give out their *Gewerberegisternummer.* In fact, I only learnt it existed thanks to the other question.

Comment: The hotel may be unwilling to share that information until and unless you have booked accommodation. My German hotel confirmation contained the very information you're asking for but I both booked and stayed there.

Comment: @DorothyThis is not the case. I would like to stay in mid-Rhein region for 5-6 days in the hotel I am booking.

Comment: The _einladende Person_ is the person or company who is inviting you. That is **not** your hotel. It's the entity that wants you to come, not who you are staying with.

Comment: @simbabque OK. So *einladende Person* is one of the cases for the Referenz. If "Referenz" is just only about an invitation from a person or an organisation (business) why would they list a hotel as a separate choice then? And where is the place to put your hotel information?

Comment: @mzu being German I have no idea unfortunately. I only translated that text for you. But I'm glad you figured it out and it's not complicated.

Comment: @simbabque, thanks, I appreciate your help. And I am looking forward to experience the beautiful valley of Rhine in Germany for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official reply from German mission in the USA:

> You only need to enter the address of your hotel + phone no.

This answers #3, and makes #1 and #2 moot for the purpose of the question.